# ROS Answers SE migration: install stack

Tags: navigation, ros-electric, stack, ros-fuerte, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!! I am working with this robot:

Robotnik Summit

```
http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/Summit
```

and I want to learn more possibilities with ROS.

The fact is, I am using ROS-FUERTE and Ubuntu 11.10 and I am not capable to install this stack:

```
http://www.ros.org/wiki/summit_description
```

Which the svn is:

```
http://summit-ros-stack.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/trunk/summit_sim/summit_description
```

And I want to include in my stacks /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks

with this comand:

```
$ cd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
$ git clone http://summit-ros-stack.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/trunk/summit_sim/summit_description
```

But the return is:

```
Cloning into summit_description...
fatal: http://summit-ros-stack.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/trunk/summit_sim/summit_description/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

It is my first time trying to install one stack by my own and I don't know how to do it.

I usually do it this way:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-electric-erratic-robot
```

For example but this erratic robot is not available in Fuerte yet and I regret neither the robotnik.

I download manually the trunk and now, I don't know what must I do to install in ros/fuerte/stacks

Can anybody help me with both installations?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33937/install-stack/) by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You seem to be trying to check out an svn repository using git. Instead of `git clone`, use

```
svn co http://summit-ros-stack.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/trunk/summit_sim/summit_description
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1